# QGIS style: trimming hashed lines or markers at the end of a line geometry

Tags: gis, line, qgis

I have a problem with the symbology/ styling of line geometries with QGIS.
I want to represent a line in such a way that it is represented by two displayed lines with hashes in between. I have managed this so far, however the hashes at one end go beyond the actual line length. It doesn't matter if the hashes are configured with the hashed lines option or as marker lines. Both possibilities lead to the same result.

The goal is that the hashed lines are truncated at the end of the line data. Unfortunately, I haven't found a direct function to do this yet (this is only possible for normal lines, which doesn't do anything for my problem). Does anyone have an idea how this could be done?
Maybe with a style code function in the function editor?

Thanks a lot!

[image]